# How do use insert statement in the google-api for BigQuery in PHP

Tags: php, insert, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a register page where the username and password are to be stored in users table in BigQuery. I'm using PHP and tried different functions on the bigquery api for php to do this but every attempt has failed so far. Would be great if someone could assist with a code snippet for syntax or other steps that may be useful for me.

I've tried all the google reference documents available and nothing has sufficient details for insert statements.
Since these are small and single inserts, I won't be need streaming inserts.

$request = new Google_Service_Bigquery_QueryRequest();

```
        $request->setQuery("INSERT INTO `Testing.users` (user,password,role) VALUE ('$userid','$password','$role')");

        $response = $bigquery->jobs->query($projectId, $request);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is strongly recommended to use **streaming insert**. It's much more faster, around max of 300ms, compared to a sync query of 2-3 seconds.

```
composer require google/cloud-bigquery
```

However if you want an INSERT job

you can use:

```
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);
$dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);

$sql="INSERT INTO `test_table` (`name`, `title`) VALUES ('Brent Shaffer', 'PHP Developer')";

$queryConfig = $bigQuery->query($sql)->defaultDataset($dataset);
$bigQuery->runQuery($queryConfig);
```

for streaming insert the example is here

```
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);
$dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);
$table = $dataset->table($tableId);
$insertResponse = $table->insertRows([
    ['col1' => $val1,'col2' => $val2],// <-- this was a row
    // additional rows can go here
]);
if ($insertResponse->isSuccessful()) {
    print('Data streamed into BigQuery successfully' . PHP_EOL);
} else {
    foreach ($insertResponse->failedRows() as $row) {
        foreach ($row['errors'] as $error) {
            printf('%s: %s' . PHP_EOL, $error['reason'], $error['message']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried using the "use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient" it throws an exception on the app engine during run time. I shall try this again and see though. Will keep you posted, thanks for the help !!

Comment: for some reason, my require 'vendor/autoload.php' is throwing an error : failed to open. I've re-installed it and made sure everything is perfect, but it still doesn't seem to work . Any inputs on what could be missing from my end?

Comment: it will be one folder above: `require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: I am getting error when I use   $table->insertRows(...  , error saying `A row must have a data key.` , what is the data key ?